# kendo ui vs slickgrid

Tags: kendo-ui, slickgrid, kendo-ui-grid

I am using slickgrid in my applications, but lately I was facing some bugs and weird behavior in slickgrid(specially related to grouping). There are lots of public and private repositories and not sure which is good.

I was thinking of using kendoui. But have below questions in mind -
1) Can kendoui provide better performance than slickgrid when UI have huge data say 50k records?
2) Do kendoui grid have same features as slickgrid have? Mostly excel style feature like automatically populating value for columns when you drag over rows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use of Slick grid can be complicated as it should be done on javascript. So the drawback of this grid is that this grid needs to be filled on document ready if we want to display it in View in MVC. Advantage of using this grid is that it is free.

On other hand, using kendo grid gives flexibility for the user to use it on View itself(as shown below). So therefore this grid runs faster as compared to Slick grid. KendoUI is a Paid UI.

```
    //Controller
    List<Student> Studentlist = new List<Student>();
    FillStudentsObject(Studentlist);
    return View(Studentlist);
    //View
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@using KendoGridWork.Models;
@model List<Student>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("StudentModel")
    .Columns(column =>
    {
      column.Bound(p => p.ID).Width(30).EditorTemplateName("#=GetID(this)#");
      column.Bound(p => p.First_Name).Width(100);
      column.Bound(p => p.Last_Name).Width(100);
      column.Bound(p => p.Division).Width(30);
      column.Bound(p => p.Standard).Width(30);
      column.Bound(p => p.Percentage).Width(50);
    })
    .Selectable()
    .Sortable()
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false)).Navigatable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(datasource=>datasource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(model =>
        {
          model.Id(p => p.ID);
          model.Field(p => p.ID).Editable(false);
        }))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[KendoUI](http://docs.telerik.com/) & [slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki)

For mine opinion Kendo UI would be better. because of Web Accessibility, simply put, is the creation of sites and applications that can be fully experienced by the broadest number of users. That includes disabled users, who typically visit the sites we create with the help of assertive technologies, like a screen reader. go ahead for Kendo UI